# Python blockless subproccess input with constant output on Windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, python-3.3

I am trying to run a command with subproccess and the _thread modules. The subproccess has a stream of output. To combat this I used two threads, one constantly prints new lines and the other is checking for input. When I pass the subproccess input through `proc.stdin.write('Some string')` it returns 1 and then I get no output. Communicate doesn't work as per most other questions I have read because it blocks waiting for the EOF although it does print the first line of the whatever was going to be returned. I saw a few solutions using 'pty' but it is not supported on Windows.

The file in the server folder is just a minecraft server if you want to try it yourself.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import _thread
import sys
# asdf
proc = None
run = True
stdout = None
stdin = None


def getInput():
    global proc
    global run, stdin, stdout
    print("Proc inside the get input funct"+str(proc))
    inputs = input("Enter Something" + "\n")
    print("YOU ENTERED:", inputs)
    print("ATTEMPTING TO PIPE IT INTO THE CMD")
    run = True

    """----------------------------------------"""
    """        Works but blocks outputs        """
    """----------------------------------------"""
    # out,err=proc.communicate(bytes(inputs,'UTF-8'))
    # proc.stdin.flush()
    # print("Out is: "+out)




    """----------------------------------------"""
    """   Doesn't write but doesn't block      """
    """----------------------------------------"""
    # test = 0
    # test=proc.stdin.write(bytes(inputs,'UTF-8'))
    # print(test)
    # proc.stdin.flush()


def execute(command):
    global proc, stdin, stdout
    proc = Popen(command, cwd='C://Users//Derek//Desktop//server//',stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=stdout, shell=True)
    lines_iterator = iter(proc.stdout.readline, "")
    print("Proc inside of the execute funct:"+str(proc))
    # print(lines_iterator)
    for line in lines_iterator:
        # print(str(line[2:-1]))
        # if line.decode('UTF-8') != '':
        print(line[:-2].decode('UTF-8')),  # yield line
        sys.stdout.flush()


threadTwo = _thread.start_new_thread(execute, (["java", "-jar", "minecraft_server.jar"], ))

while 1:
    if run and proc!=None:
        run = False
        threadOne = _thread.start_new_thread(getInput, ( ))

    pass
```

Comment: do not use `_thread` module, use `threading` module instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proc.communicate()` waits for the subprocess to finish therefore it can be used at most *once* – you can pass *all* input at once and get all the output after the child process exits.

If you are not modifying input/output then you do not need to redirect subprocess' stdin/stdout.

To feed input to a subprocess in a background thread and to print its output as soon as it arrives line-by-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import errno
from io import TextIOWrapper
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def feed(pipe):
    while True:
        try: # get input
            line = input('Enter input for minecraft')
        except EOFError:
            break # no more input
        else:
            # ... do something with `line` here

            # feed input to pipe
            try:
                print(line, file=pipe)
            except BrokenPipeError:
                break # can't write to pipe anymore
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EINVAL:
                    break  # same as EPIPE on Windows
                else:
                    raise # allow the error to propagate

    try:
        pipe.close() # inform subprocess -- no more input
    except OSError:
        pass # ignore

with Popen(["java", "-jar", "minecraft_server.jar"],
           cwd=r'C:\Users\Derek\Desktop\server',
           stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1) as p, \
     TextIOWrapper(p.stdin, encoding='utf-8', 
                   write_through=True, line_buffering=True) as text_input:
    Thread(target=feed, args=[text_input], daemon=True).start()
    for line in TextIOWrapper(p.stdout, encoding='utf-8'):
        # ... do something with `line` here
        print(line, end='')
```

Note about `p.stdin`:

1. `print()` adds a newline at the end of each `line`. It is necessary because `input()` strips the newline
2. `p.stdin.flush()` is called after each line (`line_buffering=True`)

The output from minecraft may be delayed until its stdout buffer is flushed.

If you have nothing to add around the *"do something with `line` here"* comments then do not redirect corresponding pipes (ignoring character encoding issues for a moment).

`TextIOWrapper` uses the universal newline mode by default. Specify `newline` parameter explicitly if you do not want that.

Comment: Works perfectly! What exactly does the TextIOWrapper do? Is it acting as a pseudo file to pass to the PIPE?

Comment: @ddaniels: `TextIOWrapper`  is used to decode/encode from/to utf-8, to enforce the line-buffering behaviour for `p.stdin`, to enable the universal newlines mode here. It wraps a binary file (file objects that work with `bytes`) and allows to read/write Unicode text (`str` type). If you pass `universal_newlines=True` to `Popen` then it uses `TextIOWrapper` internally (with the locale's preferred encoding)

Comment: You might like pyexpect.

Comment: @schlenk: I don't know what is `pyexpect` but `pexpect` (note: no `y`) does *not* work on Windows.

Comment: Yes, you are right on both issues (silly me to prefix py on expect and hope it matches). There was a port of the original (Tcl) expect to windows, but that was nearly like running a debugger, as Windows didn't have the needed io control stuff used in the unix expect.