# Simultaneously reading stdin and writing to stdout in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to threading so I feel as if I am missing an obvious point, but I couldn't find an previous question that pertained to this subject.

I want to make a program that writes to stdin and reads stdout of a c program. This is the code in the main program.

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from os import getcwd
import time
import random

chatter = Queue(maxsize=10)  # Queue of strings to be sent to the program


class Chatter():
    def stream_talker(self, identifier, stream):
        while True:
            if not chatter.empty():
                self.proc.stdin.write(chatter.get(True, 1))

    def stream_watcher(self, identifier, stream):
        while True:
            for line in stream:
                print line

    def main(self):
        self.proc = Popen(getcwd() + '/main', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
        Thread(target=self.stream_talker, name='stdin-talker', args=('STDIN', self.proc.stdin)).start()
        Thread(target=self.stream_watcher, name='stdout-listening', args=('STDOUT', self.proc.stdout)).start()

        while True:
            chat = raw_input('Enter chatter: ')
            if len(chat) > 0:
                chatter.put(chat)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chatt = Chatter()
    chatt.main()
```

And here is the main.c program it invokes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  while (1){
    int bytes_read;
    size_t nbytes = 100;
    char *my_string;

    my_string = (char *)malloc(nbytes + 1);
    bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);

    if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
      puts ("ERROR!");
    }
    else{
      puts (my_string);
    }
    free(my_string);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

The current issue is that while it will run, stdout is never printed.

Comment: Did you try flushing the buffers (at both ends)?

Comment: 1. you use `stream_talker` twice. You want to run `stream_watcher` too. 2. [You should force line-buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279) 3. It is [enough to start a single thread to feed input and read output at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28291847/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I am looking into both of those answers now thank you for the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your main problem is that you invoke two `stream_talker()`s and no `stream_watcher()`.

In addition, you probably don't want to busy-wait on your Queue (because that defies the whole point of using a Queue). Your code polls `chatter.empty()` as fast as it can until the queue has something in it. Use `chatter.get()` directly instead; it will block until something is available or until it hits your timeout.

Finally, you might save yourself some future confusion if you write to the `stream` argument in `stream_talker()`, and not hardcode self.proc.stdin.

Comment: there is also the block-buffering issue and the read-ahead bug

Comment: Thank you for bringing that obvious stream_talker bug to my attention. However omitting the chatter.empty()  results in the empty exception being raised, I put that in place to make sure that doesn't happen. Thanks for pointing out that I don't have to hardcode it as well.

Comment: The exception is raised after the timeout is hit (you've specified a timeout of 1 second) if the queue is still empty. If that's not what you want, just call `.get()` without parameters.

Comment: @LiamPieri: you could replace the `while True` loop with: `for line in iter(chatter.get, None): stream.write(line)`

Comment: @thepaul I see thank you for the clarification, I had forgotten what that argument was for.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I will implement that.. I am learning this module still so I though that the process would stop for good if it was not in an infinite loop.